# How to create Textview Links - XML, Android

Tags: android, xml, hyperlink, textview

I am trying to create a page with useful links within my app.  I have the names of the websites displayed as textviews on the page. I would like these to be clickable and bring the user to the intended website.

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDepression101"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Useful Links"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <!-- https://www.facebook.com/UCCHealthMatters -->

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="UCC Health Matters Twitter" />
    <!-- https://twitter.com/UCCHealthMatter -->


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03"
    android:text="HSE" />
    <!-- http://www.hse.ie/eng/ -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Aware" />
     <!-- https://aware.ie/ -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDepression101"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="UCC Health Matters Facebook" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="GROW" />
    <!-- https://grow.ie/ -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView04"
    android:text="Mental Health Ireland" />
     <!-- http://www.mentalhealthireland.ie/ -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView05"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Samaritans" />
    <!-- http://www.samaritans.org/ -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView07"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView06"
    android:text="Shine" />
    <!-- http://www.shineonline.ie/ -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView08"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Pieta House" />
    <!-- http://www.pieta.ie/ -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView09"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView08"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Reach Out Ireland" />
    <!-- http://ie.reachout.com/ -->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add `android:autoLink="web"` to your `TextView`

Comment: But does require setting the textview text to www.example.com or will it still just display as example?

Comment: add your string like `<string name="ReachOutIreland"><a href="http://ie.reachout.com/">Reach Out Ireland</a></string>` into your `values/string.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve like this way:

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
        "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>"));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Do this way for others `TextViews`